# Which classification techniques perform efficiently under homomorphic encryption

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-transformation

I am reading a [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-37682-5_1) ([pdf](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/323.pdf)) on homomorphic encryption and its use in machine learning. This paper explores classification methods like Fisher Linear Discriminant Classifier (FLD) and the Linear Means Classifier (LM), however I am curious if homomorphic encryption allows SVMs (with kernels) and Neural Networks to work efficiently. Is there performance evaluation or comparative study that exists ?

**EDIT:** I did find some early adoption of polynomial approximation of Neural networks in a research paper. Unfortunately, I cannot link it here as it is yet to be published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite new to the field of HE. What I read and as far as what I know about the algebra everything is ok if it is just addition and multiplication- in short polynomial operations. Thus the exponential is only ok if it is approximated by a polynomial. This rules out the radial basis kernel for SVMs. The linear should work.
On the other hand with neural networks if the sigmoid is used, then it should fail. Otherwise matrix multiplication should work.